# Line break for an error message in Angular/CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

When I enter 1 character in my input, I would like to display an error message `min 3 char` at the bottom of the input.

Like this example:

[image]

For now, I have this:
The error message is on the right

[image]

I can use a tag `<br>` but I think there is a better solution?

I tried this solution, but without success, I don't understand what's wrong.

```
.lastName {
   color: blue;
   bottom: 10px;
}
```

```css
        input.ng-pristine {
            background-color:yellow;
        }

        input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
            background-color:red;
        }

        input.ng-touched.ng-valid {
            background-color:green;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <style>

      
        
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
     <form name="studentForm" novalidate class="student-form">

        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="lastName" />
        <span ng-show="studentForm.lastName.$touched && studentForm.lastName.$error.minlength">min 3 chars.</span>
        <span ng-show="studentForm.lastName.$touched && studentForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">Max 10 chars.</span><br /><br />
        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the input a block level element by giving display: block;

```css
        input {
            display: block;
        }

        input.ng-pristine {
            background-color:yellow;
        }

        input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
            background-color:red;
        }

        input.ng-touched.ng-valid {
            background-color:green;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <style>

      
        
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
     <form name="studentForm" novalidate class="student-form">

        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="lastName" />
        <span ng-show="studentForm.lastName.$touched && studentForm.lastName.$error.minlength">min 3 chars.</span>
        <span ng-show="studentForm.lastName.$touched && studentForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">Max 10 chars.</span><br />
        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```